# Why os.fdopen doesn't work on fd 2?

Tags: python

Take stderr for example:

```
import os
fh = os.fdopen(2, "w")
fh.write("hello\n")
```

It doesn't output anything, what's wrong with the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to flush it out.

```
fh.flush()
```